# Redirect Form Get Request With RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, so I have a website where the user can put a search query into a form that uses GET to send the data.

When it gets sent, the url looks like: `/recipes.php?query=taco&ingredients=chili`
And I would like to rewrite it to look like: `/recipes-taco-Ichili.html`

So I added the following line to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule recipes\.php\?query=(.*)&ingredients=(.*)$ /recipes-$1-I$2.html [R]
```

I was under the impression that this would redirect the user to the masked page, but the url doesn't change.

I have `RewriteEngine on`and once the url is in the form
`/recipes-something-Isomethingelse.html` it works fine.

I have done it in the past using php, but it seemed like it would be nice if I could do it with .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the query string in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=([^&]*)&ingredients=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^recipes.php$ /recipes-%1-I%2.html [R]
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show me the page. It just says 'page found'.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm almost there. It Rewrites it, but it still has the `${QUERY_STRING}` at the end, which makes it loop while redirecting.

Comment: I got it to work, I just needed another RewriteCond to check `${THE_REQUEST}` for recipes.php.